# WPF window dialog that popup from MFC and keyboard event handler

Tags: wpf, mfc

I have some MFC application ( native C++ ) that in some case popup WPF window dialog. 
When i press on F1 on the MFC application i popup some help file. 
I also need to popup some help file ( other help file than in the MFC ) when the WPF dialog is shown and the user press on F1.

So i add keyboard event on the WPF dialog - and its work fine. 
The problem is the when i press on F1 both of the help file are jump up ... the WPF dialog and the MFC application.

I define the MFC application as a owner of the  WPF dialog - buts this is not helping me ...

What to do ?

thanks